# Mark selected sub-lists in the list they were selected from

Tags: list-manipulation

I've got this simple problem with two lists. I select some items from a list, but I want to visualize the difference between the previous list and the list that I create with `Select`.

For instance:

```
a = {{7, 0, 0, 2}, {0, 0, 2, 5}, {10, 4, 8, 7}, {7, 1, 9, 2}, {1, 3, 6, 7}, 
     {6, 9, 2, 9}, {2, 0, 7, 1}, {2, 5, 1, 1}, {9, 6, 4, 0}, {9, 9, 2, 8}};
b = Select[a, #[[4]] > 5 &];
```

I want a list that compare the two lists in this manner

```
results = 
  {{7, 0, 0, "-"}, {0, 0, 2, "-"}, {10, 4, 8, 7}, {7, 1, 9, "-"}, {1, 3, 6, 7}, 
   {6, 9, 2, 9}, {2, 0, 7, "-"}, {2, 5, 1, "-"}, {9, 6, 4, "-"}, {9, 9, 2, 8}};
```

Comment: An easy way is : `{#[[1]], #[[2]], #[[3]], If[#[[4]] > 5, #[[4]], "-"]} & /@ a`.

Answer (score 12):

```
results = a /. {x__, _?(# <= 5 &)} :> {x, "-"}
```

or

```
a /. {x___, y_ /; y <= 5} :> {x, "-"}
```

or

```
b = Select[a, #[[4]] > 5 &]; 
results=If[MemberQ[b, #], #, Flatten@{#[[;; -2]], "-"}] & /@ a
```

or

```
results = MapAt[If[# <= 5, "-", #] &, a, {All, -1}]
```

to get

```
(* {{7, 0, 0, "-"}, {0, 0, 2, "-"}, {10, 4, 8, 7}, {7, 1, 9, "-"}, {1, 3, 6, 7},
  {6, 9, 2, 9}, {2, 0, 7, "-"}, {2, 5, 1, "-"}, {9, 6, 4, "-"}, {9, 9, 2, 8}} *)
```

Comment: I was going to post `a /. {x___, y_} /; y <= 5 -> {x, "-"}`

Comment: @belisarius, fwiw, of the three variants of `ReplaceAll`, `a /. {x___, y_} /; y <= 5 -> {x, "-"}`,  `a /. {x___, y_ /; y <= 5} :> {x, "-"}` and ` a /. {x___, _?(# <= 5 &)} :> {x, "-"}` the middle one seems to be marginally faster for large lists.

Comment: Interesting, I wonder why :)

Comment: @kguler; @b.gatessucks; @belisarius


Thanks a lot. You're very kind and solved my problem in a very smart way. I hope I'll be usefull to you.

Answer (score 5):

Why `Select`? Traverse the list with `Map` and replace the appropriate part of each sublist if it fails your test.

```
Map[If[#[[4]] > 5, #, ReplacePart[#, 4 -> "-"]] &, a]
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `Reap` and `Sow` with tags, you can get both the selected elements and the diff output in one go:

```
{selected, diff} = Last@Reap[
    Cases[a, x_ :> If[x[[4]] > 5, Sow[x, "selected"], 
        Sow[ReplacePart[x, 4 -> "-"], "diff"]]], {"selected", "diff"}] ~Flatten~ 1

(* {{{10, 4, 8, 7}, {1, 3, 6, 7}, {6, 9, 2, 9}, {9, 9, 2, 8}}, 
    {{7, 0, 0, "-"}, {0, 0, 2, "-"}, {7, 1, 9, "-"}, {2, 0, 7, "-"}, {2, 5, 1, "-"}, {9, 6, 4, "-"}}} *)
```

If you want the selected elements too in your diff output, then all you need to do is to also tag them `"diff"`, i.e., change the first `Sow` above to `Sow[x, {"selected", "diff"}]`.

Answer (score 3):

If you have both lists prepared already, you can use `SequenceAlignment` and then post-process:

```
Flatten[
  SequenceAlignment[a, b] /. {deleted_List, {}} :> 
      Map[MapAt["-" &, #, -1] &, deleted], 
  1]
```

This however may not be the optimal solution for really large lists in terms of performance.

Answer (score 3):

Since V 13.1 we have `ReplaceAt`:

```
ReplaceAt[a, x_ /; x <= 5 :> "-", {All, -1}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As an exercise in visualization:

**Using `Sequence*` functions:**

```
a = {{7, 0, 0, 2}, {0, 0, 2, 5}, {10, 4, 8, 7}, {7, 1, 9, 2}, {1, 3, 
    6, 7}, {6, 9, 2, 9}, {2, 0, 7, 1}, {2, 5, 1, 1}, {9, 6, 4, 0}, {9,
     9, 2, 8}};

SequenceReplace[#, 
    k : {a_, b_, c_, d_} :> 
     If[d > 5, Style[k, Darker@Green, Bold], 
      Style[#, Gray] & /@ 
       Most@k~Join~{Style[d, Red, Underlined]}]] & /@ a // 
 Map[Apply[Sequence]]
```

or the simpler variant:

```
SequenceCases[a, {k : {a_, b_, c_, d_}} :> 
  If[d > 5, Style[k, Darker@Green, Bold], 
   Style[#, Gray] & /@ Most@k~Join~{Style[d, Red, Underlined]}]]
```

---

*Result*

[image]